# How old is Alex Summers (Havok) in X-Men: First Class?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, age

From a previous question, I saw that he was in his late teens or early twenties but I want to know a little more factual details. The comics don't even help.

How old is he?

Comment: Would you care to provide link to that another question?

Comment: The comics wouldn't help if you are referring to the First Class movie they are different continuities.  In comics Alex is Scott's younger brother but clearly that is not the case in the movies.  Also if he was in his teens in 1962 (First Class) then in Days (1973) I'd say he was in his mid-to-late twenties... which would put him in what... his sixties now?!

Answer (score 1):

[Lucus Till](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1395771/), who plays Havoc, was in his early twenties while filming X-men: First Class.

I would argue that makes this version of the character no less than 18 and no more than 25.

The comics will be of little help as:

1. The comics exist in [Comic book time](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ComicBookTime) <sub>(Warning: TV tropes)</sub> so the character has no real age there
2. The X-Men movies do not sync up with the comics in any way.

So all we have to go by is the actors age,  and the character's apparent age of 18-25.